# Distance Between Two Geo Coordinates

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, geocoding, spatial-query

I am just starting to work with spatial data in SQL Server (2008 r2).  I am looking to calculate the distance between two coordinates (miles).

```
DECLARE @source geography
DECLARE @target geography

SET @source = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT (43.420026 -83.974472)', 4326);
SET @target = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT (43.458786 -84.029471)', 4326);

SELECT @source.STDistance(@target)/1609.344 -- meters to miles
```

My query results in a value of 3.827 miles but I checked it against the site linked below and they are returning a distance of 3.85 miles.  Am I doing this incorrectly?

http://www.boulter.com/gps/distance/?from=43.420026+-83.974472&to=43.458786+-84.029471&units=m

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong. Your SQL query looks reasonable to me. But…

I'm far from an expert on spatial reference systems and geodesic stuff (have you considered asking the expert folks over at GIS SE?); nevertheless, here's three possibilites that come to my mind:

- Perhaps they calculate the distance along a straight line instead of the geodesic distance (i.e. the distance along a curved line, the Earth isn't flat after all). SQL Server's `geography` type should account for that.

  This does not seem very plausible, given that "their" distance is greater than "yours": you'd expect straight-line distance to be smaller than geodesic distance.
- Perhaps they can do the calculation more accurately than SQL Server (see note on [the MSDN reference page for geography.STDistance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933808.aspx))‌​:

  > *"`STDistance()` returns the shortest `LineString` between two geography types. This is a close approximate to the geodesic distance. The deviation of `STDistance()` on common earth models from the exact geodesic distance is no more than .25%. This avoids confusion over the subtle differences between length and distance in geodesic types."*
- Or, both calculations are somewhat inaccurate, but in opposite directions. If I'm not mistaken, the two results you're citing differ by something like 0.5%, that could just be the sum of their deviation and SQL Server's.

But I could be completely wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance and insight.  I think your third point makes the most sense.  Either way, for my purposes I dont need to be extremely accurate right now.